# pure JS handling if content text length < 0 then hide

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to handling,
if content text `length < 0` 
then set class `match-name` & `divider` style to `display none`.
it seem like not working with below code.

```js
var newsMatchName = document.querySelectorAll(".match-name");
var newsMatchNameDivider = document.querySelectorAll(".divider");

for (var i = 0; i < newsMatchName.length; i++) {
  if (newsMatchName[i].length < 0) {
    console.log(newsMatchName[i].length)
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
      newsMatchName[i].style.display = "none";
      newsMatchNameDivider[i].style.display = "none"
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="news-content">
  <div class="match-name"></div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="title">Title Text</div>
  <div class="footer">
    <span class="author">Author</span>
    <span class="spacer"></span>
    <div class="timeline">
      <span class="date">2021-04-01</span>
      <span class="time">12:15</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the "elem" in `for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)` ? And try to add a code snippet with runnable property https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

I test the length of the text in match-name

Length can be 0 or more, not <0, so use

```
newsMatchName[i].textContent.length === 0
```

but I suggest this:

```js
var newsMatchName = document.querySelectorAll(".match-name");
var newsMatchNameDivider = document.querySelectorAll(".divider");

newsMatchName.forEach((name, i) => {
  const textLen = name.textContent.trim().length;
  name.classList.toggle("hide", textLen === 0);
  newsMatchNameDivider[i].classList.toggle("hide", textLen === 0);
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-content">
  <div class="match-name"></div>
  <div class="divider">This will be hidden</div>
  <div class="title">Title Text</div>
  <div class="footer">
    <span class="author">Author</span>
    <span class="spacer"></span>
    <div class="timeline">
      <span class="date">2021-04-01</span>
      <span class="time">12:15</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected the code for you:

```js
var newsMatchName = document.querySelectorAll(".match-name");
var newsMatchNameDivider = document.querySelectorAll(".divider");

for (var i = 0; i < newsMatchName.length; i++) {
    if (newsMatchName[i].innerText.length <= 0) {          
      newsMatchName[i].style.display = "none";
      newsMatchNameDivider[i].style.display = "none"
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="news-content">
  <div class="match-name"></div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="title">Title Text</div>
  <div class="footer">
    <span class="author">Author</span>
    <span class="spacer"></span>
    <div class="timeline">
      <span class="date">2021-04-01</span>
      <span class="time">12:15</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Length can never be less than 0